# Search for string in filename Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am currently trying to find a filename that contains a certain string that is requested. For instance, I have a string `companyABC` and I am looking to search a directory for this string in a file name. I then want it to return the file I am looking for.

I tried the following using regex but that does not get a string it just checks for those letters in any order which I am not looking for:

```
$foundFile = grep(/[comapnyABC]/i, readdir Dir);
```

Is there a way to search for a certain string within a file in perl and return that file name?

Comment: my ($found_file) = grep { /companyABC/i } readdir DIR;

Comment: You could use `if ( $file_name =~ /\Q$str\E/ )`. See also [Exact string matching in Perl using quotemeta()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684182/exact-string-matching-in-perl-using-quotemeta) and http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were very close, you just had a couple of problems.

Firstly, those square brackets are changing the meaning of your regex. A pair of square brackets defines a "character class" - that is a set of characters to match. The regex will match if it finds any **one** of those characters. So you are looking for a 'c' or an 'o' or an 'm' ... etc. That's clearly not what you want. So lose those brackets.

```
$foundFile = grep(/comapnyABC/i, readdir Dir);
```

But that still doesn't give you quite what you want. Instead of returning the filename, you'll get the number of matches found. If you read [the documentation for `grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html), you'll see it says:

> Evaluates the BLOCK or EXPR for each element of LIST (locally
>   setting `$_` to each element) and returns the list value consisting 
>   of those elements for which the expression evaluated to true. In 
>   scalar context, returns the number of times the expression was 
>   true.

You are assigning the result of calling `grep` to a scalar variable. That means you are calling it **in scalar context**, which is why you get the number of matches back. To get the actual matches, you need to call it in list context. You can do that in a couple of ways. The simplest is to just assign the result to an array.

```
@foundFiles = grep(/comapnyABC/i, readdir Dir);
```

The array `@foundFiles` will contain all of the filenames that match the regex. But it sounds like you only expect one filename to match. So you can do this instead:

```
($foundFile) = grep(/comapnyABC/i, readdir Dir);
```

The only difference here is the parentheses around `$foundFile`. Often in Perl the presence or absence of parentheses make no difference, but here they make an important difference. They make the assignment into a **list assignment**, which means that `grep` is called in list context and therefore (as the documentation says) returns the actual matches, not just the count.

Comment: Very good information here. Would this find a file name where the string is in the middle of the file name? or does this only look at the beginning of the filename?

Comment: If you want a regex to only match at the start of the string, you need to anchor it with `^` (so `/^comapnyABC/i`). Without the anchor, the regex will match anywhere within the string.

Comment: If there are multiple files with the same string how would I get all those files?

Comment: If you read my answer, I think you will find it already covers that.

Comment: Ah yes missed that line!

Answer (score 2):

`[companyABC]` defines a character set that matches any of those ten characters: `c` or `o` or `m` or `p` or `a` or `n` or `y` or `A` or `B` or `C`.  So if any filename matches any one of those ten characters, it will match.  (Or any of the eight characters, since you're doing case-insensitive matching, and A/a and C/c are both in the list)

You want

```
@matching_files = grep { /companyABC/i } readdir DIR;
```

Comment: Heres another example: lets say the string is `12345678` and the file im looking for is `record12345678` will this pick it up even though the string is  not the beginning of the filename?

Comment: @user081608 Use `/^companyABC/i` to anchor the regex to the beginning of the string (will match `companyabc` as well as `companyabc123`, but won't match `123companyabc`). Use `/^companyABC$/i` to also anchor it to the end of the string (will match `companyabc` as well as `COMPANYABC`, but won't match `companyabc123` or `123companyabc`).